# Why can't I use multiple type parameters with a wildcard?

Tags: java, generics

For eg : Why can't I do this (I1 and I2 are two interfaces):

```
 List<? extends I1 & I2> myList;
```

Note that I would prefer not to add a new Interface that extends I1 and I2 as it wouldn't have any additional functionality and would only be a placeholder

Comment: While this is an interesting question I'm not sure we could answer it without getting the actual designers of java in here

Comment: Actually it's pretty obvious once you realize why :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two reasons:

The first is because Java doesn't support multiple inheritance.

The second is because this means that you cannot return an object with multiple types.

For example imagine the myList.get(i) method. What return type should that have in your example? It has to be either I1 or I2, it cannot be both.

You can define an interface which implements both I1 and I2 and then use that - however all objects added to the list would need to implement your new interface. Adding something that implements I1 and I2 but not the new interface would still be invalid.

Forget generics and try to write the method stub for .get() that returns I1 and I2 - you can't do it, it's just not legal in Java. Generics doesn't let you do it because there would be no way to convert the resulting code into legal Java code. For a more detailed discussion on that look at why Java only supports Single Inheritance as it's a part of that much larger discussion.

Comment: Effectively isn't this the same as List<T extends I1 & I2>. The object being returned does not have multiple types, it would mean that it has to be a subtype of I1 and I2

Comment: But there is no way to define that in Java. Returned objects can only have one type. In order to support it in that generics expression you would also need to add support for multiple-type objects throughout the language.

Comment: Oh!, I think I get it, when you use <T>, the compiler can replace it  with an actual data type whereas there is no data type like (I1 or I2) that <?> can be replaced with

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly - although in fact type erasure means the information from generics doesn't go through to run time the principle is still the same. :)

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't support it. You can achieve this by defining one more `interface I3` which will be extended by `I1` and `I2`

Comment: That isn't a complete solution - see my answer for why.

Comment: Yes, but why should I have to add a new interface if it is nothing but I1 + I2 without any additional functions

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own new interface that achieves the same result:

```
interface ABList<T extends A & B> extends List<T> {

}

....
ABList<X> abList = ...;
```

You have to remember that generics is **not** an attempt to extend the existing Java parameter matching system. It is more a way of tightening up the compile-time parameter checks where you would normally be tempted to cast at run-time and risk a class cast exception. Using the `?` in generics should be a very rare occurrence.